# Pandas при чтении csv файла не разделяет данные, а оставляет их в первом столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Пытаюсь разделить данные, но pandas все оставляет в первом столбце.

```
df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv',sep=',',encoding ='cp1251')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть с этой проблемой?
Прикрепляю ссылку на файл, который не могу прочитать.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RJDRRZZN9V8z5nCkFJA89jHzecrRWxBx?usp=sharing

Comment: А ничего, что вот это : df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv',sep=',',encoding ='cp1251')  отличается от того, что написано в ячейке [86]. И отличается именно параметром, определяющим вид сепаратора?

Comment: @passant А дело оказалось всё же не в этом )

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрим, что за странный такой файл, выведем на печать несколько строк:

```
with open('testdata.csv', encoding='cp1251') as f:
    print(*f.readlines()[:4])
```

Ага, у вас проблема в том, что все строчки кроме заголовка у вас закавычены:

```
Week,Date,Event_Count,FederalDistrict_Name,Event_Name
 "18,2018-05-01 00:00:00,117,Central,""Регистрация пользователя"""
 "18,2018-05-01 00:00:00,1,Far Eastern,""Регистрация пользователя"""
 "18,2018-05-01 00:00:00,10,North Caucasian,""Регистрация пользователя"""
```

`Pandas` воспринимает закавыченный текст как единое целое. У вас вся строка в кавычках, поэтому `Pandas` размещает всю строку в одну ячейку.
Самый простой способ изменить это поведение и всё же прочитать такой файл в `Pandas` более-менее нормальным образом - отменить действие кавычек, например, с помощью параметра `quoting=3` (либо задав другой символ квотирования с помощью параметра `quotechar=`, но тогда надо выбрать символ, которого точно нет в файле):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', sep=',', encoding ='cp1251', quoting=3)
df
```

Получили такой датафрейм:

```
    Week    Date    Event_Count FederalDistrict_Name    Event_Name
0   "18 2018-05-01 00:00:00 117 Central ""Регистрация пользователя"""
1   "18 2018-05-01 00:00:00 1   Far Eastern ""Регистрация пользователя"""
2   "18 2018-05-01 00:00:00 10  North Caucasian ""Регистрация пользователя"""
...
```

Далее вам нужно будет вычистить лишние кавычки из первого и последнего столбца, но это уже совсем не сложно. А вообще я бы рекомендовал всё же убрать эти кавычки из исходного файла, они там явно лишние. И грузить после этого датафрейм нормальным образом.

Comment: А вы отчаянный :-).Я не рискую открывать файлы от участников с первым сообщением, да еще и с вопросом, сформулированным таким "специфическим" способом.

Comment: @passant Если бы не гугль драйв, а какая-то левая ссылка была, я бы тоже не рискнул. А так ну интересно же )